# Unable to use quit() to end execution in Google Colab or Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

When run in Google Collaboratory of the following code should be just 1, but both 1 and 2 are printed:

```
print(1)
quit()
print(2)
```

Here is a screenshot from Google Colab. The same result holds on my local Jupiter notebook.
[image]

I searched online some examples about quit() and exit() using for loop. I ran their codes and it turns out all the expected outputs are wrong: the function quit() seems to do nothing.

If there an alternative way to achieve the algorithm like "if X, then print and all done; else do something"

Comment: What is the use case?  The answer will vary depending on the intended use.

Comment: This should exit as expected, unless you have redefined the `quit` function or have some other weird environment.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The code print only `1` as expected.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg See my screenshot. Quit function does not work in Colab.

Comment: If you're going to tag it `python`, make sure it still happens in plain Python. If it only happens in Google Collaboratory or IPython Notebook, that makes it a very different problem from something that's universal to all Python interpreters.

Comment: ...see https://ideone.com/UmXpZ3 demonstrating that, in fact, it _does not_ happen in plain Python.

Comment: Anyhow -- if what you want is to stop a loop, it's generally appropriate to use `break`. `quit()` is only when you want to completely exit the interpreter and stop running any code in it at all. It _makes sense_ for IPython Notebook and Collaboratory to disable `quit()`, since they both have other ways to exit that shut down the whole thing gracefully.

Answer (score -4):

You can try to use -
Python exit commands: exit(), sys.exit() and os._exit()